# why does firefox ignore font when printing a webpage

Tags: firefox, printing

I am running ubuntu 22.04
when I print a webpage from firefox it always seems to ignore the font on the page and print in a really small font.
this happens with both of my hp printers.  This does not happen with google chrome.
why does firefox do this ?

Comment: Exactly which version of Firefox? From deb, snap, or some other source?

Comment: Try installing Firefox with APT (see https://askubuntu.com/a/1404401/124466), and let us know if that fixes the issue

Comment: firefox 116.0.3 (64-bit) from snap

Comment: Comments are designed for US to ask YOU questions about your Question. You should [Edit] your question to add information. By updating your Question, and using the formatting buttons, you make all the information available to new readers. People shouldn't have to read a long series of comments to get the whole story. AskUbuntu is a Question and Answer site, not a conversation site. If you have an update, [edit] your Question.  If you have a new question, see  [Ask].